# How to reset a placeholder whenever you exit a search box event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got an overlay search box (check code). The search box got a placeholder "Sök", let's say the user writes something in the textbox but then exits (presses the x in the right upper corner). Then I want the text that the user wrote to be removed and the placeholder reset, so whenever the user enters the search box again the text is removed and the placeholder is back. How do I create this event?
**Code:**

```css
body{
background: white;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
padding-bottom: -1px;
}


span{
  display: inline-block;
}


.backgroundlogo{
  margin-top:-1400px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
width: 100%;
}


.container{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;

}
header{
  background: none;
}
* {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
header ::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
nav{
float: right;
padding-right: 230px;
}
nav li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 45px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
nav ul{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 25px;

}
nav a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav a:hover{
  color: red;
}
nav li:hover{
}

.fa-bars{
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.fa-bars:hover{
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.backgroundlogo{

}



.bild1{
  height: 350px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 80px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 4;
  background-image: url('Img/KBA.jpg');
  background-position: 10% 30% ;
  background-size: 180%;

}

.bild2{
  height: 350px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-top: 140px;
  margin-left: 120px;
 z-index: 3;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #3D6BB8;

}

.entrytext{
float: right;
margin-right: 90px;
margin-top: 175px;
clear: both;


}
.entrytext>h1{
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 54px;
}

.entrytext>button{
border: none;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #38b272;
color: white;
padding: 8px 10px 8px 15px;
letter-spacing: 6px;
border-radius: 8px;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 17px;
text-align: left;
margin-top:   20px;
box-shadow: 20px 15px black;
}

.entrytext>button:hover{
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #c12147;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 15px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
button:focus {outline:0;}

.fa-angle-right{
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;

}


.entrytext>h2{
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 600;
margin-top: 20px;
}
.citygalleria{
  color: #CC2244;
}


.brand{
  height: 110px;
  width: 750px;
  margin: 600px auto;
  background-color: #CFCFCF;
  clear: both;
  z-index: 11;

}




.openBtn {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.openBtn:hover {
  background: #bbb;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;

  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
}


.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin: auto;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}

.overlay .closebtn:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}

.overlay input[type=text] {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  background:none;
  margin: 0 auto;
   text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 6px solid black;
border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  color:black;
text-align:center;
  width: 100%;


}
input::placeholder {
  color: black;
}

.overlay input[type=text]:hover {
  background: none;
}

.overlay button {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:focus {outline:0;}

.overlay button:hover {
  background: #bbb;
}

.type1{
  width: 1700px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/908c2e5c96.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
    <title>Kungsmässan — Måste upplevas!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<header>

<div class="container">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Butiker</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resturang & Café</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Utbyggnad</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Öppetider</a></li>





    <div id="myOverlay" class="overlay">
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="closeSearch()" title="Close Overlay">×</span>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input class="type1" id="type2" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Sök'" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" type="text" placeholder="Sök" name="search">

    </form>
  </div>
</div>

   <i onclick="openSearch()" id="openBtn" class="fas fa-search"></i>


   <script>
function openSearch() {
  document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "block";
}

document.addEventListener('keydown',function(){document.getElementById('type2').focus();});



function closeSearch() {
  document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "none";
}
</script>


      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
</header>


  <div class="bild1">
  </div>
  <div class="bild2">
  </div>
  <div class="entrytext">
    <h1>Sveriges bästa <br/> <span class="citygalleria">citygalleria.</span> Mitt  <br/> i Kungsbacka.</h1>
    <h2>35 000 KVADRATMETER OCH ÖVER 100 AFFÄRER!</h2>
    <button type="LÄS MER" name="button ">LÄS MER<i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></button>
  </div>

<div class="brand">
</div>




<span>
<img class="backgroundlogo" src="Img/bg.png" alt="">
</span>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set the value of the input back to nothing when the closing button is clicked, the placeholder should appear again:

```js
const button = document.querySelector( 'button' );
const input = document.querySelector( 'input' );
button.addEventListener( 'click', event => {
  input.value = '';
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Sok">
<button>Close</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with setValue('') method to reset any element value.

Comment: I'm a beginner in Javascript, could you show me the whole line?